# How do you adapt / what do you have to change in your Java JPA code (Entities, etc.) if a column was manually added directly on the database Mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

A database that I am using (MySql) was added directly a new column on a table. Was should I change in the java code so my entities can still make operations with the database but now including the new column? Do i have to change just the entity class and add the column or there is more to it? Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you asking "How do I update my Java application to work with a new schema revision?"

Comment: Just change your entity : add the property.

Comment: I guess I could have phrased it like that. The table has a new field I want to know what do i have to do in Java to make it work. i ask since I have always made the creations from zero in java itself and in this case I dont know how to proceed

Comment: By the way this was the answer, thanks @grigouille